# Sending Mail with nodemailer and node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using this code for sending an email

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
  secure: true,
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: mail,
    pass: password
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: mail,
  to: emailTo,
  subject: subject,
  headers: headers,
  html: html
};
```

The problem is that the response answer is '535 Authentication Failed for EMAIL'. But the email and password are the correct ones because when I sign in 'email.secureserver.net' it success.

Maybe I should change something in the configuration ? I am looking for answers and changing the host but i didnt succeed.